# Remove duplicate rows from table with join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, duplicates

I have two table to contain state (state_table) and city (city_table) of countries

The city table is having state_id to relate it with state_table

Both the tables are already having data in it.

Now the problem

City table contains multiple entries of a city within one state. And another cities may or may not have the same city name as well

e.g.: cityone will have 5 occurrence in the city table with stateone and 2 occurrence with statetwo

So how will I write a query to keep one city for each state and delete the rest?

Schema follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `city_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `state_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

This is the sample data

```
id   state_id   city
1   1   city_one
2   1   city_two
3   1   city_one
4   1   city_two
5   2   city_one
6   3   city_three
7   3   city_one
8   3   city_three
9   4   city_four
10  4   city_five
```

Original table has 152,451 rows

Comment: please provide sample data for the same

Comment: So do you mean there are duplicate data in your table and you want to remove all duplicate?

Comment: Try editing question title so that it summarizes your problem

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Let me know it its working or not

Comment: @SaharshShah Since the table is big its taking time to return the results. am still waiting...

Comment: @hims056: duplicate city entry in each state, I have some 50 states

Comment: @hims056: i am running the query suggested by Saharsh Shah and waiting for the results. its taking too much time, i would post the result of your query once i am done

Comment: @zamil - Did you take a backup before running the query?

Comment: @hims056: Thanks a million. hugs :) It worked like charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove duplicate city with same `state_id` (duplicate records), you can do that by grouping them by `city` and `state_id` and using `MIN` or `MAX` function:

Before delete query your table was looking like

```
| ID | STATE_ID |       CITY |
------------------------------
|  1 |        1 |   city_one |
|  2 |        1 |   city_two |
|  3 |        1 |   city_one |
|  4 |        1 |   city_two |
|  5 |        2 |   city_one |
|  6 |        3 | city_three |
|  7 |        3 |   city_one |
|  8 |        3 | city_three |
|  9 |        4 |  city_four |
| 10 |        4 |  city_five |
```

You can use the following query to remove duplicate records:

```
DELETE city_table 
  FROM city_table
  LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT MIN(id) AS IDs FROM city_table
   GROUP BY city,state_id
  )A
  ON city_table.ID = A.IDs
  WHERE A.ids IS NULL;
```

After applying the above query your table will look like:

```
| ID | STATE_ID |       CITY |
------------------------------
|  1 |        1 |   city_one |
|  2 |        1 |   city_two |
|  5 |        2 |   city_one |
|  6 |        3 | city_three |
|  7 |        3 |   city_one |
|  9 |        4 |  city_four |
| 10 |        4 |  city_five |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81d94/1)

For more see [`DELETE` Syntax of MySQL.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: Doesn't your solution delete rows, if there are no duplicates? Maybe you meant `NOT IN`.

Comment: @samuil - I updated the answer. See my [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562587/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows-from-table#comment18582303_13563454)

Comment: Since you are using subquery anyway it is a bit redundant to `JOIN`, and check for `NULL`s.

Comment: @samuil - Does [this query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13563454/1369235) run successfully?

Comment: @hims056: i believe this should do the job in the original table as it deletes records in my test table, since the original table is big it will take some time for me to post the result :)

Comment: @hims056 - yep. It does almost the same thing your query does, but is easier to follow and understand.

Comment: @hims056: Thanks a million. hugs :) It worked like charm [i posted this in wrong place]

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM city_table 
WHERE id NOT IN 
  (SELECT MIN(id) 
   FROM city_table 
   GROUP BY state_id, city)
```

If you'll find this query too slow, you can create temporary table, and store output of subquery in it, then truncate original table and refill it's contents. It is a bit dirty solution, as you would have to set auto_increment column values.