# How to remove all duplicate rows except one with latest date from MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove duplicate rows from table with join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562587/remove-duplicate-rows-from-table-with-join)

My table looks like this:
`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`date`
How to remove all rows with same `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` except row with latest `date`?
There is some rows, that has `a` and `b` same and `c` and `d` NOT same.

Comment: I don't think this is exact duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM tableName 
WHERE (a, b, c, d, dte) NOT IN (SELECT a, b, c, d, dte 
                                FROM (SELECT a, b, c, d, MAX(dte) dte 
                                     FROM tableName GROUP BY a, b, c, d
                                ) AS A );
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33d07/1)

Comment: @hims056 You have written a delete query wrong check this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33d07/1

Comment: +1 for using tuples. and it works correctly, most importantly :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join with same table like this

```
DELETE table1
  FROM table1
  LEFT JOIN 
  ( SELECT MAX(`date`) as dates,a,b,c,d FROM table1
    GROUP BY a,b,c,d
  ) A
    ON table1.date = A.dates
   AND table1.a = A.a
   AND table1.b = A.b
   AND table1.c = A.c
   AND table1.d = A.d
 WHERE A.dates IS NULL;
```

### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9cd39/1)

For more see [`DELETE` Syntax of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)